# Is any version of `@openzeppelin/contracts` for `erc1155` use sol 0.5.0

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

I installed `npm install @openzeppelin/contracts --save-dev` to use token `erc1155`, my project is running on 0.5.0 version for all smart contracts and `erc1155` is using 0.8.0 and I got this error `Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.8.0".` Is any version of `@openzeppelin/contracts --save-dev` for `erc1155` use sol 0.5.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the openzeppelin github repo, erc1155 was incorporated from version 3.1.0. You can get that specific package by running `npm i @openzeppelin/contracts@3.1.0 --save-dev`.

As for the compiler compatibility, you can tweak the version in `truffle-config.js`. It should be under

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "x.x.x"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but `npm i @openzeppelin/contracts@3.1.0 --save-dev` uses `pragma solidity ^0.6.0;`  and my project is using 0.5.0 and i still try to config the version of solidity as you provide above and i got this error instead 
`CompileError: @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:98:40: ParserError: Expected '{' but got reserved keyword 'override'
    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {` 
can you help me with this ?